# SSH set non default port

Tags: linux, unix, ssh, admin, unix-socket

I am trying to change default port of SSH from 22 to 2292, Host: RHEL 7.1

I have tried:

```
1)vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config
#Port 22
Port 2292

2)reboot
```

Error

```
ssh -p 2292 root@lrmi079.pll.domin.com
ssh: connect to host lrmi079.pll.domin.com port 2292: No route to host
```

but ping to the host works

```
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1000ms
```

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that this new port 2292 is not open on your RHEL 7.1 host and the inbuilt firewall (also known as iptables) is declining the connectivity.

Check the current firewall rules:

```
$ sudo iptables -L
```

To open up a new port - port 2292 - in your case:

```
$ sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=2292/tcp --permanent
$ sudo firewall-cmd --reload
```

Check the updated rules:

```
$ firewall-cmd --list-all
```

Let me know if it worked.